# Make and call a function from components

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-component

I guess this might be an easy question, but I was wondering how and where should I define a function so that I could call it from within any component in react?

Suppose I have a function that scrolls the page to the top whenever a certain component is mounted. I have included the function in componentdidmount() of every component I needed the effect. Can I define it some where else like app.js and just call it where needed? If yes, should the function be included in render or somewhere else.

I'm using create react app by the way

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have one class based component, and a functional component.

Inside your top level component, you would have...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class MyApp extends Component {

  myLogHandler = () => {
    console.log("Hello World")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyOtherComponent clicked={this.myLogHandler}>
    )
  }
}
```

you simply pass your function, as a prop, using the syntax above!

And inside of your other component

```
const myOtherComponent {
  <button onClick={props.clicked}>HelloWorld</button>
}
```

props.clicked will refer to the props, and the function that is passed to your component, and will execute the function on click.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a utils.js file and define the function in it.
For example;

```
export default function scrollToTheTop () {
// do the logic here
}
```

And you can import and use it in the component such as;

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {scrollToTheTop} from ./utils;

class SampleComponent extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      scrollToTheTop();
   }
}
```